# Javascript find occurance position of selected text in a div

Tags: javascript, indexing

I have a string with a word five times.if i selected forth hello it should return 4

```
 <div id="content">hello hai hello hello hello</div>
```

getting selected text script

```
<script>
 if(window.getSelection){
   t = window.getSelection();
 }else if(document.getSelection){
   t = document.getSelection();
 }else if(document.selection){
   t =document.selection.createRange().text;
 }
 </script>
```

If am selecting  `hai` it should return `1`.

If am selecting  `hello hai` it should return `1`. please help.

Comment: Could there be any HTML within the `<div>` or is it guaranteed to be a single text node?

Comment: nice question. even i want its answer.

Comment: yes there is html within the div

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Assuming that the contents of the `<div>` are guaranteed to be a single text node, this is not too hard. The following does not work in IE < 9, which does not support Selection and Range APIs. If you need support for these browsers, I can provide code for this particular case, or you could use my [Rangy](http://code.google.com/p/rangy) library.

Live demo: http://jsfiddle.net/timdown/VxTfu/

Code:

```
if (window.getSelection) {
    var sel = window.getSelection();
    var div = document.getElementById("content");

    if (sel.rangeCount) {
        // Get the selected range
        var range = sel.getRangeAt(0);

        // Check that the selection is wholly contained within the div text
        if (range.commonAncestorContainer == div.firstChild) {
            // Create a range that spans the content from the start of the div
            // to the start of the selection
            var precedingRange = document.createRange();
            precedingRange.setStartBefore(div.firstChild);
            precedingRange.setEnd(range.startContainer, range.startOffset);

            // Get the text preceding the selection and do a crude estimate
            // of the number of words by splitting on white space
            var textPrecedingSelection = precedingRange.toString();
            var wordIndex = textPrecedingSelection.split(/\s+/).length;
            alert("Word index: " + wordIndex);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: If `<div id="content">hello hai  hello hello hello</div>` selecting hai should return 1 and selecting second hello should return 2

Comment: @tomjoy: That's slightly more complicated and is not clear from your question.

Comment: sorry for the obscure question. I had make it clear.I need to get the selected text index. Could you please share.......

Answer (score 3):

You'll need to use the [Range](http://dvcs.w3.org/hg/domcore/raw-file/tip/Overview.html#ranges) capabilities of the DOM. Here is how to get the currently selected range:

```
var currentRange = window.getSelection().getRangeAt(0);
```

From there currentRage.startOffset will tell you the position of your selection within the file. So you'll need to compare that with the start range of your element:

```
var myContent = document.getElementById('content');
var divRange = document.createRange ();
divRange.selectNodeContents (myContent);
```

Now you can compare the divRange.startOffset with your selection startOffset and determine which one you're on.

Comment: `startOffset` is the position within `startContainer` which is the container node of the range's start boundary, not within the whole document. `startContainer` may not even be a text node.

Comment: @tomjoy, Tim Down's example is the best starting place. In order to differentiate between different words you'll have to create an array of all the words and find the starting index of each word. Then you'll be able to find out which instance a particular word was.