# How to get index of highlighted words?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

i need help to find highlighted words index from a sentence. consider this sentence, i need to higlight the second **international news**, and get the index of those words (index is start and end of word in sentence, e.g Barack Obama is 0 and 1, Donald Trump is 8 and 9)

> Barack Obama appeared to take a swipe at Donald Trump on Wednesday , saying he would “ advise , if you ’ re president ” to avoid international news . The former US president was speaking as a guest at an event for Splunk , an international news and software firm , when he was asked how he parsed information while in office .

my best try is:

```
function getTextSelection() {
  let selection = '';
  // get the higlighted text string
  if (window.getSelection) {
      selection = window.getSelection().toString();
  } else if (document.selection && document.selection.type != "Control") {
      selection = document.selection.createRange().text;
  }

  const wordLength = selection.split(' ').length;
  // theSentence is the full sentence split to array of word
  const initial = theSentence.indexOf(selection.split(' ')[0]);
  return [initial, initial + wordLength - 1];
},
```

with that code, if i highlight second **international news** it will return [27, 28] which is the first occurence of the words. how i can get the second?

Comment: indexOf() method returns the position of the first occurrence.

Comment: @Casper indeed, do you know any function or made up function to get specific coordinates of words inside sentence?

Comment: check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11558527/javascript-find-occurance-position-of-selected-text-in-a-div